# How to change MicroK8s default network interface

Tags: microk8s

The documentation for ports and services states that the microc8s will configure APIs to be accessible on the [default network interface](https://microk8s.io/docs/services-and-ports):

If I have eth0,1,2 which will be considered default? And how am I supposed to configure that?
To clarify - I need to bind all public APIs that microk8ks brings up to eth2 for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This [comment on the k8s forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfz03.jpg) suggests creating the cluster first on your main interfaces. Then switching configuration to your 2nd interface.

- On the `master` node generate `join` tokens & check services are running:

```
microk8s add-node 

... # run the join command for your internal NIC on the other nodes

# check cluster details
kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName --all-namespaces
```

- I then stopped every node
- To configure all the addresses in the [microk8s docs](https://microk8s.io/docs/configure-host-interfaces) to bind to my internal NIC I used the following to quickly configure every node:

```
NIC=ens4

# use inet6 for ipv6 address
PROTOCOL=inet
LOCAL=$(ip -f $PROTOCOL addr show $NIC | grep $PROTOCOL | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)

# set --bind-address
#-------------------
FILES="/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-apiserver
/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-controller-manager
/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-scheduler
/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-proxy"

for x in $FILES; do
    sed -i "1s/^/--bind-address=$LOCAL\n/" $x
done

# Kubelet settings: node-ip sets INTERNAL-IP & ordering is important
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
sed -i "1s/^/--healthz-bind-address=127.0.0.1\n/" /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet
sed -i "1s/^/--node-ip=$LOCAL\n/" /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet
sed -i "1s/^/--address=$LOCAL\n/" /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet

# change kube-apiserver localhost addresses
#------------------------------------------
FILES=$(find /var/snap/microk8s/current/credentials -type f -name *.config)
PORT=16443

for x in $FILES; do
    sed -i "s/127.0.0.1:$PORT/$LOCAL:$PORT/" $x
done
```

- After every node was configured I started the `master` followed by the rest of the nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microk8s has several services that bind to interfaces.  In your case, I'm assuming you want to bind the kubelet APIs.  They are already bound to all interfaces, but you can apply configuration if you want to restrict access:

```
# /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet
--address=192.168.1.1
--node-ip=10.0.0.1
--healthz-bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

https://microk8s.io/docs/configure-host-interfaces#kubelet-7